# React Native screen missing updated data from backend after navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native

### The scenario:

In my React Native app I have the following `handleSubmit` function:

```js
    const handleSubmit = async () => {

        const createdAt = new Date()

        const dishData = { dish, createdAt }

        try {
            const response = await addDish(auth.userId, auth.accessToken, dishData, photoData, axiosPrivate);
            navigation.dispatch(
                CommonActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    routes: [{ name: 'Home' }],
                })
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

The `Home` screen to which the user then navigates has a `Tab.Navigator` in which the first `Tab.Screen` is `Dishes`.

The `Dishes` component loads a list of dishes from the nodejs backend. It does that through the `fetchDishes` function, which is a Redux action.

In **Dishes.js**:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (isFocused) {
    fetchDishes(auth.userId, auth.accessToken, axiosPrivate)
  }
}, [isFocused])
```

In **dishActions.js**:

```js
export const fetchDishes = (userId, accessToken, axiosPrivate) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchDishesRequest())
        axiosPrivate.get(`/dishes/user/${userId}`, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}})
            .then(response => {
                const dishes = response.data
                dispatch(fetchDishesSuccess(dishes))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(fetchDishesFailure(error))
            })
    }
}
```

### The problem:

When the user navigates to Dishes immediately after `handleSubmit` is called, `Dishes.js` fetches the list but the new dish is not there yet. If the user moves to the other tab and comes back then `fetchDishes` brings the updated data.

I guess the HTTP response has not yet arrived the first time but I would think the `async await` in `addDish` would take care of that.

### The question:

How do I make sure that the new added dish is fetched once the user navigates from the screen in which they add the dish to the screen that loads the list of dishes?